# Bucle while JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Soy principiante en JavaScript, estoy trabada con el siguiente bucle while: alguien me dice que estoy haciendo mal? El bucle me da indeterminado

```
i=0;
a=1+i;

while (a<5){
  i++;
}
```

Entiendo que en cada vuelta el bucle debería sumar una unidad a i, en la vuelta 5 el bucle debería parar, pero me lo sigue ejecutando infinitas veces, ¿xq no incrementa i?

Gracias!

Comment: Por que la condición es que `a<5` pero tu incrementas `i`

Comment: Claro, pero a = 1 + i, por eso me confunde. En la segunda vuelta i=1 por ende a=2.

Comment: Nop, `a` esta declarada fuera del bucle

Comment: Aaaaaah Perfecto! Ahora entiendo el razonamiento! Mil gracias!!

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que estás usando mal la *variable de control*. Dentro del cuerpo del programa incrementás la variable **i**, pero la condición del *while* la hacés con la variable **a**.

Por esta razón, al no tener condición de salida, el bucle es infinito.

Deberías hacer algo así:

```
i = 0;            // Esta es la variable de control
a = 1 + i         // Esto siempre valdrá 1 (se ejecuta solo una vez)
                  // después se ejecuta 5 veces el while y termina el programa.

while (i < 5) {   // observá que cambié la variable a por i
  
// Aquí dentro del cuerpo del ciclo, poné las instrucciones
// que quieras que se ejecuten en cada iteración
  
  i++;    // Aquí se incrementa solo la variable i

}
```

Espero que te sirva, ¡saludos!

Comment: Siiiii genial! Ya entendí el razonamiento! Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¡Un placer! Me alegro mucho.